# 404 SysVol entries in webserver's logfiles

Tags: windows-server-2008, webserver, http-status-code-404, domaincontroller

Our 404 error logs show a lot of /SysVol http requests on our Windows Web Server 2008 for our website. It only has a webserver role and I believe that SysVol requests are meant for Domain Controllers? What's causing this and what would be the best solution to deal with these 404 requests?

I'm using code that access employee records via Active Directory (ldap) and the server is not trusted for delegaton in case this is related to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these requests coming from external IPs ? They are probably trying to p0wn you

Answer (score 0):

The sysvol share generally gets created and shared out when a server is promoted to a domain controller.  I'm assuming that your web server is not a DC and not in an Active Directory domain?

As for how to deal with it, if you're behind a firewall, you could block everything except ports 80 and 443 for instance.  I hope that your webserver is behind a firewall.  Seeing traffic like that isn't all that unusual considering it's on the internet.